# Leer hardware externo

Tags: c#

¿Cómo podría saber cuando un aparato externo fue conectado a mi ordenador y a raíz de eso pedir una contraseña para ser aceptado?

Comment: por conectado te refieres a un puerto USB ? ese aparato ejecuta algun soft que requiere autenticacion?

Comment: Si, por decir asi, yo conecto un USB o teclado y que me pida permiso ejecutando una ventana en la que me pida una contraseña

Comment: conozco desde c# que puedes detectar cuando se conecta un dispositivo, ahora no creo que puedas retenerlo latente para pedir autorizacion, lo detectaras y podras removerlo desde codigo, pero mientras tanto estara activo

Comment: Pero puedo hacer aparecer una ventana en la cual pida una contraseña para continuar? y si no se ingresa removerlo?

Comment: si eso puedes hacerlo, pero en el mientras tanto el dispositivo igual sera accesible, como comente puede detectar y puedes removerlo, pero no veo conozco que puedas dejarlo en standby en medio del proceso en el cual ingresas la contraseña

Comment: Pero puedo bloquear teclas no? como win + e para abrir el editor si es asi.. me explicas como puedo detectarlo y removerlo si deseo?

Comment: que teclas ? no se sipone que es un dispositivo usb, esto podria ser cualquier cosa que conectes

Comment: Hola @Axel. en el futuro utiliza solo una etiqueta de lenguaje de programación, no múltiples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para detectar el USB mediante c# hay varias formas podrias ayudarte con WMI

[Detect Insertion and Removal of USB Drive C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/detect-insertion-and-removal-of-usb-drive-c-sharp1)

o podrias ayudrte con librerias

[A USB Library to Detect USB Devices](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60579/A-USB-Library-to-Detect-USB-Devices)

lo cual hara mas facil la manipulacion del usb y sus acciones

Los hay quienes usan los handler de las api del sistema operativos

[Detecting USB Drive Removal in a C# Program](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program)

como veras posibilidades para trabajar con el usb hay muchas y variadas

Ahora el tema es como evitar que el dispositivo este activo mientras espera confirmacion